# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS issue with connecting to TV via HDMI

Tags: hdmi

I am trying to connect my laptop to my TV via HDMI and whenever I do the tv screen goes black and the laptop screen goes black as well. Then every couple seconds the mouse cursor will flash on the black screen of the laptop.

After some time (maybe 15 minutes or so) it will give up trying to duplicate to both displays and will just display on the laptop. From here I can have it only display on the TV and this will work. But if the laptop gets restarted or goes to sleep, whenever I turn it back on it will switch back to "duplicate displays" and repeat.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem.

You can fix it with an update:

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with *Mirroring* and *Joint Displays*

Updating did not help.

I was able to temporarily fix it for *Joint Displays* by setting 
**external hdmi display as a "Primary Display".**
This can be done in Settings>Devices>Displays

After doing this, *Mirroring* seems to be also working normaly




I do not know why this happens, so I am adding my system details and syslog output.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on Lenovo YOGA 900-13ISK.

Syslog monitor connection **before** choosing "Primary Display":

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uXIr-gm0bc6O5r0h6Ij7SCFILiXehuqf

Syslog monitor connection **after** choosing "Primary Display":

https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Tc0z5bBKPejpYPnq_mdInBpJZoev3Eb

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also How do I write a good answer? for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)